# check if n is a probable prime

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-factorization

[image]

I tried to calculate n one by one by using Pari but it seems out of range. So I think I might need to simplify the modulo equation by using the order of 2,3,5,7 mod n but I do not know how to simplify it.

Comment: In a general-purpose language, you would need to reduce by the modulus during the [exponentiation process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring). I don't know if Pari has something better.

Comment: The bounds for $n$ are $10^{11}$ and $10^{11}+25$

Comment: I wrote a command called "powmod", but thanks to gammatester, I now know that this is not necessary, PARI/GP allows to calculate it with an easy trick , I was not aware of.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your code, but you should not directly compute $a^{p-1}.$ Use e.g.

`p=10^11+25; Mod(7,p)^(p-1) = Mod(64827127026, 100000000025)`

which is **not** out of range.

$ p=100000000001$ is not probable prime because `Mod(7,p)^(p-1)= Mod(495415670782,1000000000001)`, but for $p=100000000003$ all results are 1 and $p$ is indeed prime. But the test is not 'perfect':

The next Carmichael number is
$p=100023777217 =7\times 13\times  17\times  23\times  73\times  97\times  397$
and all results (except for $a=7$, which is a divsor of $p$) are $1,$ e.g. `p=1000151515441; Mod(5,p)^(p-1) = Mod(1, 1000151515441)`.

The following Carmichael number is $100165237201=37\times 73\times  631\times  58771,$ the test gives $1$ as the result for all $a=2,3,5,7.$

So $100165237201$ is a "probable" prime, although it is not prime.

Comment: (+1) because I was not aware of the possibility to calculate for example $7^{p-1}$ modulo $p$ this way

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer! This really helps.

Answer (score 1):

Using gamma-testers command , just input

```
? select(m->Mod(2,m)^(m-1)==1,[10^11..10^11+25])
%7 = [100000000003, 100000000019]
? select(m->Mod(3,m)^(m-1)==1,[10^11..10^11+25])
%8 = [100000000003, 100000000019]
? select(m->Mod(5,m)^(m-1)==1,[10^11..10^11+25])
%9 = [100000000003, 100000000019]
? select(m->Mod(7,m)^(m-1)==1,[10^11..10^11+25])
%10 = [100000000003, 100000000019]
? select(m->isprime(m,2)==1,[10^11..10^11+25])
%11 = [100000000003, 100000000019]
?
```

You get the two probable primes $10^{11}+3$ and $10^{11}+19$, which are actually prime (which is shown in "%$11$"

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! By the way, may I ask what does "->" mean? Sorry, I am a beginner of Pari.

Comment: The select-command allows to determine the elements of a set satisfying some condition.

Comment: Got you, thank you very much!